# Menu in WP doesnt show in IE-11

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, internet-explorer-11

I have the next site:

[id.factor.ua](http://id.factor.ua)

> If you open it in IE-11, you **cannot** see sub-menu in header.

Please, help me understand how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I confirm that there is a issue in IE 11, you can solve it however by specifying the `!important` element clauses in your CSS rule `ul.art-hmenu ul::before {}` and `ul.art-hmenu::after, ul.art-hmenu ul::after{}` (around line 1059).

The problem is that this rule is overwritten and interpreted wrong way by IE.

However, I see that you generated your theme with older version of `Artisteer` software. Always check for updates for this software, because this *may* solve such issues in future.

Comment: sorry me, but I done all what you say on test site. BUT nothing fixed. You can check it there: http://portalchik.factor.ua - can you help me in this issue, please?

Comment: Try re-ordering the CSS rules in your `style.css` file. As you know, the CSS is parsed by the browser line-by-line, in sequence order, so put those important rules at very bottom of the file.

Comment: Have some else ideas ?