# Submenu in Wordpress doesnt show IE-11

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with submenu in ONLY IE-11.
The following menu in different browsers and versions is OK but in IE-11 does not appear.

[image: screenShot]

This site has an address: [there](http://portalchik.factor.ua/)

I already asked a question on this topic, but the result has zero.

Ask for help from experienced people!

[Menu in WP doesnt show in IE-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213766/menu-in-wp-doesnt-show-in-ie-11)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Menu in WP doesnt show in IE-11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213766/menu-in-wp-doesnt-show-in-ie-11)

Comment: sorry, but it not right mind

Comment: Just because you don't get the correct answer straight away doesn't justify reposting exactly the same question - see [point 1 here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the compatibility of css property which you are correctly used in the css file, some of attribute are supported like "div.clipped" in your code

Comment: media scrren{
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.2px;
}
remove from you css file and its work file